# Are these two words,'rampallian' and 'fustilarian',common to English native speakers?

Tags: early-modern-english

I came across these two words in a video on youtube.(How NOT to swear in English 10:45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02hOrOrjjYw) It's said both of them come from Shakespear's works.And i haven't found them in OED.

So I wonder whether they are common words to the native speakers?Are they able to recognize them?And are English native speakers required compulsorily to learn Early Modern English in highschool?Or maybe Latin,Greek,French languages?And are these courses compulsory?

Comment: Asking the question "should English native speakers learn X" is an entire philosophical, political, economic, etc. subject that millions of people have heated arguments about.  You won't get an answer to that question here!

Comment: 99.9% of native English speakers would not recognize those words.  Shakespeare is often "translated" into modern English in American high schools. Ancient languages like Latin and Greek are not compulsory; in fact, they are rarely taught in public high schools.

Comment: @JohnFeltz Sorry that maybe i haven't expressed precisely.I mean,whether the native speakers are required by school's curriculum to learn Early Modern English.Since in my country,it's compulsory for us highschool students to learn Classical Chinese.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Since i came across these words on a youtube pedagogical video for foreigners,i assumed that maybe they are common to native speakers.Turns out the answer is no.Thanks a lot !

Comment: @dubina The educational systems in English-speaking countries are generally not centralized.  Some schools will require students to study Shakespeare, others will not.  Some will require foreign languages, others will not.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Is that actually true? When I was in high school some of the Shakespeare we read was abridged and it was all pretty heavily glossed, but I don't believe it was actually *translated* (as in ["Oh, Romeo, Romeo, why do you have to be Romeo? Forget about your father and change your name."](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/romeojuliet/page_80.html)) except when *we* did the translation as an exercise. My oldest are starting Shakespeare in high school now, and this still seems to be the same for them. But maybe other schools do it differently?

Comment: @1006a: For your reading pleasure ... It's a trend. https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/answer-sheet/wp/2016/12/13/students-remove-shakespeare-portrait-from-english-department-at-ivy-league-school/?utm_term=.4b14c657500f

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Ah, dropping Shakespeare from the required higher-ed curriculum I can certainly believe. But that article says Shakespeare is still widely-taught in US high schools (he's in the Core Curriculum!) and doesn't mention translation. It wouldn't surprise me if many high school students are accessing such translations, since they're so readily available online, but I suspect the *assigned* text is still mostly the original language. (Which certainly doesn't mean that most high school grads would know these particular obscure vocab words. *Henry IV* isn't really the go-to high school play.)

Comment: @1006a: But it's the curriculum for those majoring in English, not just for all undergraduates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those words are in the OED. (They might not be in the Oxford dictionary online, the OED is not the same.)

These words are not used in modern English. Its not clear that they were used in Early Modern English.  Fustilarian is described as a nonce word, meaning it has only one clear use (in Henry IV Part 2, Act2 scene 1).  It is possible that Shakespeare just made up this word for the sake of the insult. They would not be understood out of context by most native English speakers.

The lesson that the video seems to be teaching is that you can be creative in your insults.  You don't have to use dictionary words.  You can make stuff up. Shakespeare, Dahl and Ferrell all invent new words to use as insults.

On the matter of education, I can only speak in detail for the English system.  Everyone studies English. Nearly everyone will study English Literature up to age 16, and Shakespeare will be part of that study. Very often just one play will be studied (often Macbeth, because it is dramatic and *short!*).

Students do not study the Early Modern English, except to understand the play that they are reading. Most modern editions of Shakespeare have modernised punctuation, and notes on the text, including footnotes to explain any obsolete works. Here, though, the explanation is hardly needed. The "Page" is insulting "Fang" who has come to arrest "Falstaff". This kind of insult is intended to be comic.

Many students will (attempt) to learn a language (French and Spanish are most popular) up to age 16. A small minority study Latin, and an even smaller number study Greek.

Comment: Thanks a lot.And generally,are there any other literature except Shakespear's written in Early Modern English(or maybe more earlier,like Chaucer) in the high school curriculum of the English system?In China,there are about (if my memory is correct)more than 15 proses written in Classical Chinese (which is much diffenrent from Modern Standard Mandarin) and even more poetries in high school curriculum! And many Chinese children began to recite poetries written in Classical Chinese from three or four years old.

Comment: Chaucer is an option for the post 16 Literature curriculum .Only a minority would attempt it.. AQA requires students to write about a nineteenth century novel of their choice see https://www.aqa.org.uk/subjects/english/gcse/english-literature-8702/specification-at-a-glance.  https://www.aqa.org.uk/subjects/english/as-and-a-level/english-literature-b-7716-7717/specification-at-a-glance  There is no notion of "Classical English".